# Chrome extension copy and paste

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm building a private chrome extension.
I have `popup.html` with two buttons, one is copy and other is paste.

The logic is like this:

1. Press copy button in popup, and copy some form data
2. Go to other website and press paste and inject in other form

So I use `chrome.extension.sendMessage` to detect clicking on popup buttons and listen to messages `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener` where I switch what action was fired an execute some script.

The things is that I can get the information, I know how to inject it but I dont know where to save it so I can use it in different tab.

Does anybody has some ideas?

```
function dispatch(action) {
    return function() {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({directive: action}, function(response) {
            this.close();
        });
    }
}



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    copy = document.getElementById('copy');
    paste = document.getElementById('paste');

    copy.addEventListener('click', dispatch('COPY'));
    paste.addEventListener('click', dispatch('PASTE'));
})
```

Comment: Please note that `chrome.extension.*` messaging functions are deprecated: use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`/`onMessage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use local storage to store the value you want, paste it and then delete it again.

You can store values in the local storage using:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ 'KEY': 'VALUE' }, function(){});
```

And you can retrieve from storage using:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('KEY', function(items) {
    //use the retrieved data with items.KEY
});
```

And in the `manifest.json` you need to add the following line:

```
"permissions": ["storage"]
```

For instance, if the key I'm using is 'SNT', I set using:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ 'SNT': 'VALUE' }, function(){});
```

And I retrieve it using:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('SNT', function(items) {
    $("#divID").text(items.SNT);
});
```

If you wan't to see a working example you can check [this](https://github.com/rafaelcpalmeida/Simple-Notetaking) GitHub repository.

Comment: thanks dude, i was thinking to use localStorage, but thats just for tab, didint know about chrome.storage

Comment: @Hiero you can even set the storage to be synced across devices :)

Comment: i dont know why when i copy i recive some errors like innerHTML is undefined, happened to you before?

Comment: It shouldn't. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/durizu/edit?html,js,output, tells me innerHTML its not a function but work, but it trows error first time

Comment: Are you placing this code in the popup js file? I never got this error before